# How to set fillstyle='none' in lineplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a lineplot such that there is no filling for the markers. However, the problem I face is the legend still has filled legend, although the markers are not filled in the figure. The following illustrates the problem:

```py
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

ax = sns.lineplot(
                data=tips,
                x='size',
                y='tip',
                hue='sex',
                ci=None,
                style='sex',
                markers=True,
                fillstyle='none',
                markeredgecolor=None,
                markersize=10,
            )
```

[image]

Could anyone please tell me how to make the legend non-fill as well? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The same question has been posted on github and will be resolved, but in the meantime, the following can be addressed. `handler, label = ax.get_legend_handles_labels();handler[0].set_fillstyle('none');handler[1].set_fillstyle('none');ax.legend(handler, label)`

Comment: @r-beginners you should make this an answer. I can't find any other comparable answers for this issue., or simply how to set the legend fillstyle. Also link the github issue in the answer. thanks

Comment: I have checked the comments from the developers of seaborn . Unfortunately, it was not taken into account in the design. My comments are the only way to address this. Either you self-answer or I do, both will be beneficial to the referring user.